# Autolayout constraints not working iPhone 6 and 6 Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout

My app displays the views properly on iPhone 5, but on 6 and 6 Plus, the views do not fill the screen horizontally. I tried adding autoconstraints through Storyboard, but they do not make a difference.

Below are what I have in Storyboard for the blue view (and subviews), and a screenshot of the app for the Plus.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are your training spaces negative?

Comment: Because he hasn't unticked "relative to margins". Untick "relative to margins" and set the constraints to 0.

Comment: I recommend removing all constraints and use is very user friendly lib for constraints https://github.com/Masonry/Masonry

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have already encounter this problem.
It is because of margins. You just have to uncheck Constraint to margin in Interface Builder.

[image]

And you should also check directly on the constraint (Click on it).
[image]